How use loop variable in column or row number?
I wrote a simple apps script to repeat set formula:
for (var i=157;i<=160;i++)
{
  spreadsheet.getRange('E'+i).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=concatenate(F&i:AG&i)');

 }

but sheet E157 to E160 always is

how use [i] into sheet number....

Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are just trying to repeat a formula down a column, it is unclear why you would use a script for that as the same can be done much more easily with spreadsheet functions such as byrow(). See What is the XY problem?

One way to do that is to use template literals, like this:
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (let i = 157; i <= 160; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(`E${i}`).setFormula(`=concatenate(F${i}:AG${i})`);
  }

